# How should I approach error handling in PHP? Specifically user input

Tags: php, error-handling, error-logging, error-log

I've been using PHP for quite a long time now, and I do enjoy it. However, it has come to my attention that my error handling is not up to scratch and for the new project I am working on, I want to adopt a proper error-handling method.

I'm wondering how to handle user input specifically, but also more generally any errors.

I have a case as below as an example:

```
function check_email($email){
   if(empty($email)){
      $error='You must enter an email address';
      error_log($error);
      header('Location: page.php?error='.$error);
      exit();
   }
   if( *doesn't match regex* ){
      $error='Not a valid email format';
      error_log($error);
      header('Location: page.php?error='.$error);
      exit();
   }
}
```

I want to both be able to revert to the user with the error message, and also log it in the error_log document.

The above method works fine, but it is super messy code, or at least it feels messy. Any ideas how I can clean this up? I want to be efficient with it because easy-to-write error catchers mean I will write more of them instead of being lazy

Edit: yes, I could wrap that in a function of it's own

```
function er($error){
   error_log($error);
   header ('Location:...);
}
```

Surely there is a more elegant, native solution though?

Comment: `error_log`, `header`, and `exit` can all be moved out of the conditionals.

Comment: @user3783243 thanks for the input - like my edit you mean? Or is there a different way?

Comment: Yes, I personally would not want my error logs flooded with non-errors. This looks like trying to log debugging details.

Comment: I suppose that is what I'm trying to do in a sense... Want to make sure I catch if users are able to submit with obscure values etc so I can investigate how/why. Would you suggest making a debug_log document, and directing this information there instead, in a similar way to my edit with error_log?

Comment: You would probably want to log `$email`, not `$error` in that case, or both. You could append that to the redirect. Your access logs should have the data there if you require it.

Comment: Is this really the way to do it though? Is there not a more elegant solution?

Comment: Let's be clear on the terms first. There are actual [PHP Errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) of various types. These also include `E_USER_ERROR`, `E_USER_WARNING` and `E_USER_NOTICE` that you can use for logging/displaying errors _not caused by core PHP, which you determine as errors_. These will be handled by your/default error handler. Dealing with invalid user input is something different. There is no native way to provide feedback to the user _on issues that are independent of code execution_. How you want to inform them is up to you, there is no standard to it.

Comment: This looks like _validation_, not error handling. These aren't errors in the sense that the program crashes, they're just undesirable input values, according to your program's requirements. Most applications don't log that kind of stuff (unless they're _very_ heavily into analytics or tracking), and certainly not in the error log file.

Comment: I normally put the user validation errors in the $_SESSION and reload the page showing an apropriate feedback to the user. Real errors should be handled by the PHP Exception mechanisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have utilised comments below to come up with two individual functions for soft errors and returning user errors

For user errors:

```
function return_error($msg){
    $_SESSION['error']=$msg;
    header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)");
    exit;
}
```

For soft errors / unusual behaviour (make_file() function just makes a file if not exist)

```
function soft_error($e){
    $trace=debug_backtrace(-1);
    if(isset($trace,$trace[0],$trace[0]['file'],$trace[0]['line'])){
        $file=BASE_DIRECTORY.'logs/soft_error.log';
        make_file($file);
        $log=fopen($file,'a');
        fwrite($log,'['.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'] File: '.$trace[0]['file'].' - Line: '.$trace[0]['line'].' - Error: '.$e.PHP_EOL);
        fclose($log);
    }
}
```

For hard errors, there is error_log() or they will be logged automatically based on server settings, so that is fine